# simple Java calculator - while loop until answer is 0

Tags: java, while-loop

Really new to java and having some trouble with this assignment. The assignment was to:

> Write a simple calculator program that prints a welcome
>   message, accepts a simple arithmetic expression from the user, and
>   performs the requested operation. Your  program should repeat this
>   until both operands are 0 and then exit.

It's running fine but I'm not sure how to get a handle on the While Loop so that the calculator will continue until the answer is 0. Sorry if this is a really basic question. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Calculator{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Welcome to CSC 210 Calculator by Bob the Builder!");
        System.out.println("Enter an integer operation: ");

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int x = input.nextInt();
        String operation= input.next();
        int y = input.nextInt();

            while(x + y != 0){

        if(operation.equals("+")){
            System.out.println(x + y);
        }

        else if(operation.equals("-")){
            System.out.println(x - y);
        }

        else if(operation.equals("*")){
            System.out.println(x * y);
        }   

        else if(operation.equals("/")){
            System.out.println(x / y);
        }

        else if(operation.equals("%")){
            System.out.println(x % y + y);
        }


        else {
            System.out.println("Operation is invalid.");
        }


                System.out.println("Enter an integer operation: ");
                if(x + y != 0);
                                break;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What you can do is create a `bool flag = false`and run your code until the `flag` is false. Once the operation is `=0` set your flag to true.

Answer (score 0):

use switch case in place of if else statement

```
if(a !=0 && b!=0)
{
switch(ch)//ch is where you stored the operator
{

case '-': System.out.println(a - b);
break;
case ' +':System.out.println(a+b);break;
}
else
{
 System.out.println("Enter an integer operation: ");}
```

Answer (score -1):

To solve the problem you mentioned above.

> Write a simple calculator program that prints a welcome message, accepts a simple arithmetic expression from the user, and performs the requested operation. Your program should repeat this until both operands are 0 and then exit.

you should pay much attention to the following tips:

1. "until both operands are 0", so you can just loop out on the condition "x+y != 0", for example, x=5,y=-5,you can't just loop out.
2. "repeat" means you should assign new int value to the x and y variable in the while loop.

***here's the code, may help you***

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Calculator{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Welcome to CSC 210 Calculator by Bob the Builder!");
        System.out.println("Enter an integer operation: ");

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int x = input.nextInt();
        String operation= input.next();
        int y = input.nextInt();

        while(x != 0 && y != 0){

            if(operation.equals("+")){
                System.out.println(x + y);
            }
            else if(operation.equals("-")){
                System.out.println(x - y);
            }

            else if(operation.equals("*")){
                System.out.println(x * y);
            }   

            else if(operation.equals("/")){
                System.out.println(x / y);
            }

            else if(operation.equals("%")){
                System.out.println(x % y + y);
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Operation is invalid.");
            }
            System.out.println("Enter an integer operation: ");

            x = input.nextInt();
            y = input.nextInt();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: add 'operation= input.next();' in the while loop.